# Can multiple castings of Glyph of Warding be stored in different objects at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, traps

*Glyph of Warding* looks like it is going to be a very fun and useful spell once I learn it, but in its description I don’t see any mention of whether is can be cast multiple times to store spells in multiple objects. I’m guessing there is a verdict on this, does anyone know it?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [our many previous questions about *glyph of warding*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+glyph+of+warding+is%3Aq) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, they can, because *glyph of warding* lasts until dispelled

The [*glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) spell's duration is listed as (PHB, p. 245):

> **Duration:** Until dispelled or triggered

It also does not require [concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration):

> You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

Nothing in the spell description says that previous castings of the spell end when you cast it again (as, e.g., [*mage hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) does). As a result, previous castings of *glyph of warding* remain active even if you cast the spell again.

### There are other limits on the spell

Note that the spell has the following material component:

> (incense and powdered diamond worth at least 200 gp, which the spell consumes)

This is its own limiting factor - you can't just spam it an unlimited number of times, no matter how much time you have (the casting time is 1 hour). You need the components each time you cast the spell, and they're consumed per each casting.

The other significant limitation is also stated in the spell description:

> If the surface or object is moved more than 10 feet from where you cast this spell, the glyph is broken, and the spell ends without being triggered.

No matter how many times you cast it, the surface or closable object you cast it on can't be moved more than 10 feet from where it was when you cast it. If it is moved, then the spell is wasted with no effect.

---

A somewhat tangential note: You also can't simply choose end non-concentration spells with a non-instantaneous duration (such as *glyph of warding*) even if you wanted to, except by any means specified in the spell description. Per the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=13):

> **Can a spellcaster dismiss a spell after casting it?**
>
> You can’t normally dismiss a spell that you cast unless (a) its description says you can or (b) it requires concentration and you decide to end your concentration on it. Otherwise, a spell’s magic is unleashed on the environment, and if you want to end it, you need to cast *dispel magic* on it.

For *glyph of warding*, this usually isn't much of an issue, since you can often just move the object the glyph is stored in or scratch/damage the surface it's inscribed on. It would only really be an issue if you were unable to move or damage the glyph without triggering it (per the trigger you decided on when you originally cast *glyph of warding*).

But the fact that this is even a question makes it clear that a non-concentration spell doesn't end early unless the spell specifies conditions under which it does.